# htaccess rewrite first directory as filename

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I was wondering how I would perform a htaccess rewrite, as explained below.

domain.com/filename/testing123 --> domain.com/filename.php?/testing123

Where "filename" is the name of a php file. This "filename" can change, and anything after the "filename" is added after the "?".

Another example would be:

domain.com/abc/other/information/etc --> domain.com/abc.php?/other/information/etc

Thanks,

Connor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `^([^/]+)` to match everything up to the first `/`, onto which `.php` will be appended, and `(.*)` to match everything else which will be appended after `?` via `$2`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)$ $1.php?$2 [L]
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. Only problem is, if the file doesn't exist it returns a "500 internal server error", any idea how to fix this?

Comment: After changing the debug log level, and increasing the LimitInternalRecursion, when navigating to a file that doesn't exist, instead of receiving a "500 internal server error",  the following happens: http://printscreen.it/srD4lJ9BLI

Comment: @xConMz See addition above to prevent rewriting if the request includes `\.php` to guard against a rewrite loop.